# Why doesn't R Shiny accept text input set by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, shiny

I am trying to build an R Shiny app without a ui.R file and nearly got it working but stumbled over the final hurdle. Below is a simplest working demonstration of the problem:

1. The index.html file defines two buttons, one named 'RAND' which is controlled by jQuery, and a second named 'ADD1', which is controlled by R Shiny. I also have two textboxes named 'temp' and 'out'.
2. The goal of this dummy program is for 'RAND' to load a random number into 'temp', and for 'ADD1' to then increment the value stored in 'temp' by 1.
3. The 'RAND' button works fine, but the 'ADD1' button produces 'NA'. The funny thing is that if I modify the 'temp' value by hand and then click 'ADD1' again, it does produce the correct value!
4. My questions are: why does the program behave as it does? And how can I make 'ADD1' work without having to manually retype the contents of 'temp'?

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="RAND" name="RAND">RAND</div>
<div id="ADD1" name="ADD1" class="action-button">+1</div>
<p></p>
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
<input id="temp" name="temp" type="text" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="out" class="shiny-text-output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is server.R file:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){ 
    observeEvent(input$ADD1, {
        output$out <- renderText({ as.numeric(input$temp) + 1 })
    });
});
```

And finally, this is my Javascript code (test.js):

```
$(function(){
    $("#RAND").button()
    $("#RAND").click(function() {
        $("#temp").val(Math.random());
    });
    $("#ADD1").button()
});
```

Comment: I believe I read a similar question before. Basically Javascript modified values are not recognized by shiny inputs.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass dynamic content generated by Javascript to Siny/R?

Comment: There is an undocumented feature of Shiny that allows you to send data directly to Shiny from JS: https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [warmoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190526/warmoverflow)'s suggestion, I managed to answer my own question:

index.html remains unchanged

server.R becomes:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){ 
    observe({
        input$randval
    })
    observeEvent(input$ADD1, {
        output$out <- renderText({ as.numeric(input$randval) + 1 })
    })
})
```

and test.js becomes:

```
$(function(){
    $("#RAND").button()
    $("#RAND").click(function() {
        val = Math.random();
        $("#temp").val(val);
        Shiny.onInputChange("randval",val);
    });
    $("#ADD1").button()
});
```

Note that the value stored in $(#temp) is not really used for anything and could be removed. I just left it in the code for comparison with my initial formulation of the problem.